# Flutter Gridview scrolling horizontal

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm working on flutter web and I want my gridview scroll direction horizontal but when I added `scrolldirection: Axix.horizontal` it rotated the gridview. I know to make this easy I can use `ListView` but it takes too much code to make it responsive on the web. I just want the gridView itself to manage its `crossAxisCount` by screen width to become responsive. So I need help on how to make GridView scroll direction horizontal. Thanks

```
 int gridCrossAxisCount;
    if (size > 1600) {
      gridCrossAxisCount = 4;
    } else if (size > 1300) {
      gridCrossAxisCount = 3;
    } else if (size > 800) {
      gridCrossAxisCount = 2;
    } else {
      gridCrossAxisCount = 1;
    }

Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 300,
        child: GridView.count(
          // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
          crossAxisCount: gridCrossAxisCount, //Screensize grid count
          childAspectRatio: 0.60, //1.0
          mainAxisSpacing: 0.2, //1.0
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0, //1.0
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.indigo,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you include the screenshot when the GridView rotate?

I think your code works fine with Axis.horizontal on. The problem might lie in the logic when calculating gridCrossAxisCount/ number of child items.

When Axis.horizontal is on, the mainAxis will now be horizontal and the crossAxis will be vertical.

Thus if the axisCount is 1, then all items will be display in 1 line only, but if it's 4, they will be display in 4 lines, which with 4 children in your example is not enough to cause overflow outside of Viewport and enable scrolling.

Comment: I thought the mainAxix and crossAxis dont changed. Now solve my problem thanks..